# Running an included PHP file

Tags: php, html, include

I have a php script (I'll call the main script) that includes another script. The pseudo code is this

```
include '.../somescript.php'

if(some conditions are met){
          show the contents of somescript.php
}
```

I only want this script to be shown on the screen (not redirected to that page). It's mainly HTML, but I'm not sure the best way to show the contents. I could wrap it in a function, showScript() which echos all the HTML, and call this function in my main script:

```
include '.../somescript.php'

if(some conditions are met){
          showScript();
}
```

But I was wondering whethe rit is possible just to run the script directly as an addition to my main script? I'm sorry if that last phrase sounds a bit garbled, I'm not sure how to express correctly what I mean.

Comment: Do u want this include and if statement etc to be displayed as it is displayed in SO here? as an output in html?

Comment: The script contains a couple of function, mainly database queries and session checks then displays lots of HTML. I want this script to be run as part of the main script, because I dont want the user to be redirected to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "somescript.php" file is all HTML, you can simply do:

```
<?php
  if (some condition) {
      include('../somescript.php');
  }
?>
```

That will make the contents of "somescript.php" display on the screen if it is all plain HTML.  If there is PHP in that file, it will be executed when "some condition" is met and the file is included (all function declarations and such will be accessible after that point).

Let me know if you asked something else and I misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 1):

Create two seperate script one which includes all sql queries and a array of output which can displayed on HTML.. and another file as only HTML file then include the query.php on top of mainscript.php and under the if statement include the showhtmlscript.php which includes html,

array variable output from query.php, say $output, can be used in showhtmlscript.php like

```
<table>
<tr><td>$output['name']</td><td>$output['age']</td></tr>
</table>
```

you require this

```
include(query.php);

if(something is set){
include(somehtmlscript.php);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I undestood you right you can use buffering.

```
ob_start();
include '.../somescript.php'

if(some conditions are met){
  echo ob_get_contents();
}
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if (some conditions are met) {
      include('../somescript.php');
  }
?>
```

or go with option of output buffering

```
<?php
ob_start();
include '.../somescript.php'

if(some conditions are met){
  echo ob_get_contents();
}
ob_end_clean();
?>
```